# Spring 3.1 and jBPM 5.2 (+ JSF2/Richfaces4) integration

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces, spring-3, jbpm

I have a project that uses Spring3.1, Hibernate3.5/JPA2, JSF2/Richfaces4.1, & Java EE Security.  I now want to integrate jBPM 5.2.

Are there available jBPM5-Spring3 integration examples?  Has anyone done this successfully?  Should I be looking at a different BPM/workflow engine, perhaps jBPM was a bad idea?  (All the examples I have found reference much older versions of Spring and/or jBPM.)

I am hoping that there will be some simple Spring configurations (& perhaps additional jars) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I  worked on a project with spring3 and jBPM 5 for a two past years,it takes 2 month to build a simple project with jBPM without spring and other technology.
It seems that you have not enough knowledge about jBPM ,it's not just a simple jar files to be added to your project ,It has database and tables and if you want to use Drools in your project it's harder .
I suggest you to use Facade pattern to build the class which initialize your knowledge Base and rules.
You have to write custom nodes and service on demand .
It depends on your deadline of project .
jBPM is too flexible and of course it's hard to maintain,because you have to customise it on your demand,but these day customers prefer it because it just sounds interesting and flexible!
and by the way I think [jboss documents](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/userguide/) are the best for jBPM ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for Spring + jBPM5 integration.  I found the sample(web-example.rar.zip) in the following discussion which works.  It is based on the well known performance evaluation sample.

https://community.jboss.org/message/725143#725143#725143

You need to have jBPM5 installed and successfully started in order for this to work. It is using REST service calls to jbpm-console which is part of jBPM install.
Also, i had to modify the app to list group tasks for users mary and john and subsequently claim the tasks from group tasks list.

You may also want to take a look at Activiti which is basically jBPM4.  It has better Spring Integration (CDI, spring managed transactions etc.,)from what i understand. Hope this helps.